# Can I know what called applicationShouldHandleReopen ?

Tags: cocoa

I'm looking to differenciate a dock clic from a click on the app icon in the finder.

Can I know what called  `applicationShouldHandleReopen` or is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:` is sent to the application's delegate. Delegate messages are normally sent by the delegating object, which in this case would be the application object.

The application object sends that message to its delegate in order to handle the reopen-application Apple Event. So, to find the sender, install your own Apple Event handler for that event and [get the sender from the event](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/technotes/ic/ic_505.html). (The sample code is in Pascal and uses Apple Event Manager, but you can translate it to Objective-C and NSAppleEventDescriptor.)

That said, what you're doing is very dubious from a UI perspective. Reopening is meant to do the same thing no matter which application is reopening you—and it is not limited to the Finder or the Dock. In the common case, it is literally the user trying to launch the app while it is already open.

It may make more sense to only do your “reopen” behavior when no windows are open. Cocoa's built-in document-based-apps support does this automatically; if you don't respond to `applicationShouldHandleReopen::` or you return `YES`, the application tries to open a new document. You can perform the same check (it even tells you whether you have any windows open) and perform your desired behavior under the same condition.